# How can I access the query profile from the snowflake connector?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am exploring the different ways that can monitor information programmatically. For this specific use case,  if any data spills into the SSD, I want the sized of the warehouse to be increased for the next set of queries.

I have already explored:

- [The Maximized vs Auto-Scale](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/warehouses-multicluster.html#maximized-vs-auto-scale)
- [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html) - I was unable to find the equivalent to the query profiler

Is it possible to access information on SSD spillage on a specific query id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a spillage metric stored in query_history, which makes what you are attempting complicated to do programmatically.  Until they add that metric to the query_history, you'll have to size warehouses a bit less scientifically.  What I have found to be useful, however, is to leverage bytes_scanned from query_history as a metric to determine whether the warehouse is performing the scans optimally.  Do some research on your queries to determine what the range of bytes_scanned to spillage is for each warehouse size, and then leverage that.